# Blank page when including jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to add a jQuery in my PHP script. Everything goes well except when adding the jQuery script. The page then goes blank.

Here is my code:

```
function site_header() {
    echo "<html dir=\"rtl\"> 
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-
        scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;\">
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
    <title>Arabsfun :: تسالي العرب</title>
    <link href=\"css/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">";

    echo Pulse::css(); 
    echo Pulse::javascript(); 
    echo "</head>
<body>
    <div id=\"wrap\">     
        <div class=\"header\">
            <div class=\"logo\">
                <a href=\"index.php\"><img src=\"images/logo.png\" alt=\"Arabsfun\" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class=\"clear-float\">
            </div><br>
        </div> 
    <div class=\"content\">" . navbar() ." </div>
        </center>" ;
}
```

I then use the function `site_header()` to start the header on the page.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: if the page goes blank, check the error log of your webserver (i.e. apache). chances are you find a PHP error there.

Comment: What code are you using to add jQuery?

Comment: do you include js by using `Pulse::javascript(); `

Comment: you're missing a closing body tag.

Comment: JQuery shouldn't break it. Can you post what the `javascript()` and `css()` functions are doing? Also, where are you adding JQuery?

Comment: What is the code for these: echo Pulse::css(); 
 echo Pulse::javascript();

Comment: By the way. I'm not sure about the way you are using the above code, but it is better to echo plain html from php like this:  function site_header(){ ?> <html>.... <? echo $smth_else; ?> <div>....<? } ?>

Comment: I don't know PHP, but isn't the `echo` inserting HTML *inside* the `site_header()` function?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reference to jQuery in that code at all.  I'm going to assume that you typed something like:

```
<link href=\"css/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"jquery.js\">
```

You need a closing `</script>` or else the whole page will be treated as script and nothing will be emitted.

Comment: i typed it right: 
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='http://arabsfun.net/m/js/pulse.core.js'></script>";

Answer (score 3):

I came across this as well. The answer for me was to use a script end tag instead of ending it with the slash in the single tag.  IE wouldn't take it.

This is what I had that didn't work...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#variables.jQueryURL#" />
```

This is what I changed it to that did...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#variables.jQueryURL#"></script>
```

*(There's a ColdFusion variable in there, but it doesn't matter for this issue.)*

Answer (score 0):

Put it simple as html and include it. You have done nothing for which server side scripting is needed (for the header).

Comment: i'm using it as function 
 echo Pulse::javascript();

Comment: fyi, the page load then the content disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst editing your code I noticed unequal tags. Your `<body>` tag is not closed and there may be others.